# How can I dynamically create class methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In Rails we can call "Person.find_by_attribute" where 'attribute' is dynamically placed by attributes in the 'Person' migration. I want to replicate this logic n my Person class without rails and call 'find_by_attribute' for the attributes. What I have so far:

```
class Person
  def attributes
    [
      { id: 1, nice_attribute: "something" },
      { id: 2, nice_attribute: "another thing" },
    ]
  end

  def find_by_id(id)
    attributes.select { |d| d[:id] == id }
  end
```

But defining a find_by like this could bloat the class quickly. How can I achieve dynamic def setting?

Comment: The way `find_by_attribute` is actually done in rails is with [method_missing](https://apidock.com/ruby/BasicObject/method_missing).

Comment: But you can use `Person.singleton_class.define_method` as well

Answer (score 0):

*I'm reasonably sure this is not how `Rails` does this, but here is some implementation that might assist you:*

What you have defined there is a `Singleton` class and you should be aware of how to dynamically define attribute records in such a class before committing to that design. It might be a good choice, but you should be feeding that class an access point to search through records defined elsewhere. Regardless, the below will get you started:

```
class Person
  @@attributes = { id: Integer, nice_attribute: String }
  
  # getter method
  def self.attribute_types
    @@attributes
  end

  attribute_types.keys.each do |attr|
    define_singleton_method :"find_by_#{attr}" do |value|
      # logic
    end
  end
end
```

Then you will be able to call `Person.find_by_id` or `Person.find_by_nice_attribute`

When you implement it may be better for you to have a `PersonRecord` module that collects records from a database and the `Person` class might be an instance like so:

```
class Person
  def initialise(opts ={})
    define_find_by_methods
  end

  def attribute_keys
    # stub method, but should be collecting this information dynamically
    [ :id, :nice_attribute ]
  end

  def define_find_by_methods
    attribute_keys.each do |attr|
      # no longer using define_singleton_method here and define_method is a class method you will have to send it to self.class
      self.class.send(:define_method, :"find_by_#{attr}") do |val|
        # logic
      end 
    end
  end
end
```